# Animating "src" attribute

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

I have an HTML document. It looks like this:

[image: original]

When the user hovers "stackinfo" image, I want it  look like this:

[image: hovered]

My code for image:

```
<img src="/Resources/Images/MainMenu/logo.png" name="Logo" width="100" height="30" class="MainMenu" id="Logo" />
```

I know how to change the `src` of the image on hover, but how can I animate this?

(I want to do it with jQuery)

What I have already tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('img[name="Logo"]').hover(function(event){
         $(this).fadeIn(function(event){
             $(this).attr("src","/Resources/Images/MainMenu/logoHover.png");
         });
       },
       function(event){
         $(this).fadeToggle(function(event){
             $(this).attr("src","/Resources/Images/MainMenu/logo.png");
         });  
       });
});
```

Comment: If you're thinking about fading and stuff, you can't animate something by just swapping out the image source, you'll need two elements where you fade one out and the other one in.

Comment: something like this?http://jsfiddle.net/necolas/fpfZb/

Comment: I'd use a sprite image. It saves you (at least) one HTTP-request, and you can make it work with CSS alone (by changing the `top` property on `:hover`).

Comment: @NullPointer, this is what I tried. In an edit! But it is a complete disaster!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all your replies, but I found a method that works great!

This is the CSS code:

```
#Logo.MainMenu{
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    background: url(/Resources/Images/MainMenu/logo.png);
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 200ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 200ms ease;
    transition: all 200ms ease;
}

#Logo.MainMenu:hover { 
    background-image: url(/Resources/Images/MainMenu/logoHover.png); 
}
```

and on the HTML page:

```
<div id="Logo" class="MainMenu"> &nbsp; </div>
```

Comment: IE8 doesn't support CSS3, including transitions

Comment: See http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions . IE8+9 has no support, Firefox works, Chrome works with a prefix, opera doesn't animate `background-position` correctly, IE10 works.

Comment: I realised you can transition a background even if it's an image ;-)

Comment: then, could you upvote my question, or my answer here please?

Answer (score 4):

You can't animate the `.src` value directly with jQuery.

You will need to use two images, positioned on top of one another so one can be faded in on top of the other.

Both images should be preloaded or precached so there is no delay for an image to load after setting `.src`.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/n52Fr/

```
$(".container").hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".fadeTop").fadeOut(1000);
}, function() {
    $(this).find(".fadeTop").fadeIn(1000);
});​


<div class="container">
    <img src="http://photos.smugmug.com/photos/344291068_HdnTo-Th.jpg">
    <img class="fadeTop" src="http://photos.smugmug.com/photos/344290962_h6JjS-Th.jpg">
</div>​ 


.container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 150px;
}

.container img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function troca_imagem(url) {
    $('#foto_grande').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 500, function () { document.getElementById('foto_grande').src = url; });
    $('#foto_grande').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 500);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Edited my answer based off of the edit the OP made. Below uses a css sprite and animates the opacity using css3. Note this will not work in any IE9<.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/rahEJ/3/)**

**[More in depth explanation](http://css-tricks.com/fade-image-within-sprite/)**

```
.sprite{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:url(http://www.somethinghitme.com/Post%20Images/sprite.png);
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
.sprite span{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    background:url(http://www.somethinghitme.com/Post%20Images/sprite.png);
    background-position: left -100px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -moz-transition:    opacity 0.5s;
    -o-transition:      opacity 0.5s;   
}

.sprite:hover span{
 opacity: 1;   
}
```

​
    ​

Comment: The question is about how to animate this, so it would be nice if you could add a css transition to the demo.

Comment: @Loktar I never downvoted, in fact I think this is a pretty good solution.

Comment: the effect is nice, but I want something like fade effect.

Comment: Loktar beat me to it, darn it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could animate the opacity to zero, use the callback to change the image source and bind an event handler for when the image loads that animates the opacity back.

```
$('.sprite').on("mouseover",function(e){
    $(this).animate({
        opacity: 0
    },1000, function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.sprite').animate({
                opacity: 1
            },1000);
        },50);
        $('.sprite').css("background","url(someurl)");
    });
})
```

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/nHC9U/

Answer (score 1):

You can't really animate the `src` attribute, but

If your goal is to fade from one image to the other, place them above each other and animate the opacity of the top one:

http://jsfiddle.net/RPYGv/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="...">
  <img src="..." class="on-hover">
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper img{
  position: absolute;
  top:0; left:0;
}
.on-hover{
  opacity: 0;
}​
```

JS:

```
$(".wrapper").hover(function(){
  $(".on-hover", this).animate({opacity:1},"slow");
},function(){
  $(".on-hover", this).animate({opacity:0},"slow");
});
```

​

Answer (score 0):

The JQuery color plugin will allow you to animate colors.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color

So you could have an png with transparent background and animate the background of the container holding the png. If you can do your text in a websafe font, then you could animate that too...

Or you can make your SVG image, embed the svg xml directly into your html (probably not going to work in older versions of IE since they have terrible SVG support w/o svg plugins)

Using the jquery.color.js we just add a hook to allow the svg fill property and then make a hover function like:

```
jQuery.Color.hook('fill');

var animationSpeed = 200;

$('#svgwrapper svg').hover(    
    function(){    
        $(this).animate({backgroundColor:'#000000'}, animationSpeed)
        .find('path').animate({fill:'#ffffff'}, animationSpeed);
    },                         
    function(){
         $(this).animate({backgroundColor:'#ffffff'}, animationSpeed)
        .find('path').animate({fill:'#000000'}, animationSpeed);
    }
);
```

Here is a working fiddle of the SVG method. Works in IE9 and current versions of firefox, opera, chrome and safari

http://jsfiddle.net/webchemist/hBHBn/11/