# Jquery Onmouseover change img attr with effect

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery onmouseover to change the src of an image like this:

```
$( ".myimage" ).mouseover(function() {

   $('.myimage').attr('src', 'imageHover.png');

});
```

My question is... How do I add a transition effect to the code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no CSS (<=3) transition for the `src` attribute. You'll have to add another `img` element and use some kind of a custom transition with jQuery (like `.fadeOut`)

Look at these threads for instance:

[Animating "src" attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314405/animating-src-attribute)

[JQuery Switch Img Src with fade effect](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-switch-img-src-with-fade-effect)

---

If you need the effect to work when the image is hovered, like you showed in your post, you can do it with only CSS using two different images.

By default, show only the regular image. When the container is `hover`, hide the first one with opacity: 0 and its `CSS transition`, and show the other one.

**[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/f5sfzmk8/)**

```
div {
    position: relative;
}
img {
    position: absolute;
    transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
}
#b {
    opacity: 0;
}
div:hover #b {
    opacity: 1;
}
div:hover #a {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can give the fade effects like this

```
$("#image").hover(function() {
    $("#image").fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $("#image").attr("src",$("#image").data("first"));
    }).fadeIn(1000);
    return false;
},function() {
    $("#image").fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $("#image").attr("src",$("#image").data("second"));
    }).fadeIn(1000);
    return false;
});
```

Working example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HpmN7/855/)