# Jquery FadeIn image on hover with SwapSource

Tags: jquery, html, image, fadein, swap

I want to make a fadeIn and fadeOut on second image but not sure where to write the function

```js
var sourceSwap = function(){
 var $this = $(this);
 var newSource = $this.data('alt-src');
  $this.data('alt-src', $this.attr('src'));
  $this.attr('src', newSource);
}
$(function(){
  $('img.xyz').hover(sourceSwap, sourceSwap);
}) ;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="xyz" data-alt-src="img/map.jpg" src="img/colourmap.jpg" width="95%" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Animating "src" attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314405/animating-src-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$('.xyz').fadeIn(1500).delay(0).fadeOut(1500);
    $('.xyz').delay(1000).fadeIn(1500);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="xyz" data-alt-src="img/map.jpg" src="http://www.apicius.es/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/IMG-20120714-009211.jpg" width="50%" />
```