# duration of img src switch, animates immediately

Tags: gsap, scrollmagic

I have a logo in a header and on scrolling down, I'd like to invert the colours. I'm using scrollmagic. I've already set the image up with a reversed version.

This is what I have currently:

```
var logo = $('header.banner .brand img'),
    logo_org = $('header.banner .brand img').data('original'),
    logo_alt = $('header.banner .brand img').data('reverse');

var brandLogo = TweenMax.fromTo("header.banner .brand img", 0.15,
      {onUpdate: function() { $(logo).attr("src", logo_org); }},
      {onUpdate: function() { $(logo).attr("src", logo_alt); }, ease: Linear.easeNone});

    // image src switcher
    new ScrollMagic.Scene({
      triggerElement: ".section-1",
      triggerHook: 0.5
    })
    .setTween(brandLogo)
    .addTo(controller);
```

.section-1 comes into view and the rest of the header animations begin, but the logo has changed to the reversed version the moment the page loads.

If I add:

```
duration: "100%"
```

it has no effect, the animation still triggers immediately. I've tried different trigger hooks, different delays, etc. all to no avail. What on earth am I missing? Apologies if this is something painfully obvious, but I've only just really begun dabbling with scrollmagic and gsap.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to animate the src attribute. 
The src attribute can have one value at a given time not a percentage of two values.

To achieve what you're trying to do you could have two image on top of another and adjust the opacity of both with "autoAlpha" in GSAP.

Or look at this similar question for some working fiddles => [Animating "src" attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314405/animating-src-attribute)

Best solution would be to use an SVG of your logo and animate the different fill property of your logo to the different colors you want.