# Adding a slide animation in a react carousel

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to remake the [carousel](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/carousel/) from `react-bootstrap` using pure JS and React.

So far my carousel automatically changes to the next slide every few seconds and loops back to the beginning. It also can show a specific carousel slide on a button click.

However, I am unable to copy the right-to-left sliding animation because I am using `slice` to render my slides. How would I edit my code to include a sliding animation like bootstrap?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const slides = [
  {
    src:
      "https://res.cloudinary.com/tpostr/image/upload/v1553865338/paparouna/IMG_7638-01.jpg",
    alt: "slide 1",
    caption: "slide 1"
  },
  {
    src:
      "https://res.cloudinary.com/tpostr/image/upload/v1553865338/paparouna/IMG_7621-01.jpg",
    alt: "slide 2",
    caption: "slide 2"
  },
  {
    src:
      "https://res.cloudinary.com/tpostr/image/upload/v1553865337/paparouna/IMG_7615-01.jpg",
    alt: "slide 3",
    caption: "slide 3"
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [start, setStart] = useState(0);
  const [end, setEnd] = useState(1);

  const first = () => {
    setStart(0);
    setEnd(1);
  };
  const second = () => {
    setStart(1);
    setEnd(2);
  };
  const third = () => {
    setStart(2);
    setEnd(3);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setStart((start) => start + 1);
      setEnd((end) => end + 1);
    }, 3000);

    if (end === slides.length + 1) {
      setStart(0);
      setEnd(1);
    }

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    };
  }, [start, end]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {slides.slice(start, end).map((slide, i) => (
        <div key={i}>
          <img src={slide.src} alt={slide.alt} />
          <p>{slide.caption}</p>
          <button onClick={first}>first</button>
          <button onClick={second}>second</button>
          <button onClick={third}>third</button>
        </div>
      ))}
      <p>{start} start</p>
      <p>{end} end</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

My [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/carousel-3oip0?file=/src/App.js:0-1680)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your three images are not shown **together** in the html page, you could not slide-animate them. Why don't you actually show them all and switch between their position like regular slider?

If you change images by changing the `src` attribute, there's no way for animation. Please refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314405/animating-src-attribute), and continue from there.

Sorry to disappoint you... Have fun hacking!

But here's a pure js slider [link](https://splidejs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it would be possible to achieve the animation effect in this way because you're switching b/w images using src attribute. I found this link, it seems to be working without using any external library. Check it out: https://dev.to/cooljasonmelton/css-transitions-in-react-build-a-root-beer-carousel-1mnb